# CSS triangles with background photo overlapping complicated sections

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, png, css-shapes

There are quite a few threads circulating about CSS triangles but none of them seem to address the layout I'm supposed to be working on.

I have a few sections where either there is a background of a full-bleed style image, or an offset image with text.

Obviously, if I could just use PNG's pre-cut to the width of the page that would be great but I don't think it would work here.

Rather than appending triangles the usual way with solid colors, I thought it may be possible to put a new spin on this whole gimmick, cutting out an "innie" triangle from the n+1 divs and then applying a negative margin to make it look like there was a triangle, when really there is just a cleft in each of the sections and an overlap.

Would that work? How else could one get this effect?

I mocked up a picture in Imgur.

[image: css triangle layout]

The layout is in bootstrap so any solution that takes that into account would be very helpful. Thanks for your help in saving "Gotham".

Comment: Before I get voted down so I can no longer, please see this diagram I just made further explaining it. The outcome of your link looks different but I would like to find an approach that more resembles this:

http://i.imgur.com/FWeyzWQ.png


The final result would look like a yellow div with a point, but in reality all of the work was on the gray div.

Comment: I also wanted to add that the suggestion that Harry linked is quite interesting and I'm trying to see if the 'tooltip on top' example in number 4 may work for this. Suggestions 1+2 are not applicable, and #3 would take a lot of margin work and z-index to get this to work as well as a lot of manipulation of the png's in photoshop.

Comment: Ok, If you look at the image in the question and compare it with the linked question, you would find that they are duplicates. The image in comment shows it is not a like for like duplicate but I would still say it is close enough because I feel you can still achieve that using the same methods mentioned in the linked answer. And finally, no the downvotes are not for a duplicate question but probably more because you haven't shown us any attempt/code.